# Excplicitly call base or overridden method

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, abstract, extend

I have some C# classes that are extended and have overridden methods.

```
public class BaseClass{
    public abstract void method(){return 0;}
}

public class OverClass : BaseClass{
    public override void method(){
        // some code
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Inside an overridden method, I can call `base.method()` to call its base class's original method.

1) How can I do that from outside that class? So that I could explicitly call BaseClass's method from a OverClass's object reference.

2) From a BaseClass's object, can I call OverClass's method?

3) if the method is static, from a BaseClass's static main, can I call OverClass's method?

I need that because some methods in BaseClass have reusable code that doesn't need to be overridden, and other methods that are abstract/virtual and have specific OverClass code. So, from a code in BaseClass, I need to call OverClass's overridden methods, not BaseClass's abstract/virtual ones.

Comment: An `abstract` method cannot have body, you mean `virtual` instead? For the rest, you cannot with standard ways.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need specialised method, that will not be overriten or concrete method that will not be marked as abstract.

```cs
public class BaseClass{
    public abstract void method(){ return 0; }
    public void concrete(){ method(); }
}

public class OverClass : BaseClass{
    public override void method(){
        // some code
        return 2;
    }
}    

//You can call concrete like that:
instanceOverClass.concrete();
instanceBaseClass.conctere();
```

2. Yes. But ONLY if you have instance of OverClass boxed as BaseClass, not if this is instance of OverClass

```cs
BaseClass instanceOverClass = new OverClass();
(OverClass)instanceOverClass.method();
//Note that here we will call overriden method from OverClass class
instanceOverClass.method();
```

3. You always can call static methods form everywhere in your code, but you need to remember that static methods are not passed with inheritance so you would call BaseClass.method();

Edit: I would like to note this anwser doesn't cover reflection, witch would do exacly what you want but, reflection is very very VERY slow.